# Meaning of the phrase "think something"

Tags: meaning

Here it is in context:

> When people appeared in Australia, many species died off. This is true of Europe. Think woolly mammoth.

What does it mean and why there is no article before "wolly mammoth"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. It is an idiom used by article-writers. I think of it as having implied quotation marks, so it really means

> Think "woolly mammoth".

i.e.

> Think of the concept "woolly mammoth".

But this is not a very convincing argument.

I think you just have to accept this idiom "Think [name of a concept>]".

Comment: Exactly, no doubt about it.

Answer (score 1):

"Think woolly mammoth" is not quite grammatically correct, but it's a conversational and emphatic gambit Americans sometimes use. It is, however, basically shorthand for "think of woolly mammoths as an example of the premise."

Comment: Being an imperative has nothing to do with whether there is an article (or, for that matter, a preposition). "Think about a woolly mammoth" is an imperative. So is "Consider a woolly mammoth", but "consider woolly mammoth" does not make sense.

Comment: The OP didn't ask about the missing preposition, but it was my bad to think article. I thought the OP was asking about the missing pronoun, for some reason. I will change my answer.

Comment: It is grammatically correct. In English, to draw someone's attention to something in writing we say: Think [x]. This is used as an example of some preceding idea.

Comment: If you are talking about descriptive grammar, then yes, it's grammatically correct, because as both of us mentioned, it is something that people say and people understand. It's a correct idiom. But the OP may have been confused because the idiom doesn't follow the rules of prescriptive grammar, so I was simple confirming that that was true. The rest of your comment basically repeats what I said in my answer.

Comment: But it is grammatically  correct, in fact. It's merely an imperative of the verb think....

Comment: Indeed, @Lambie. It would not be _idiomatic_ if it were not, in fact, an idiom; but I challenge you to name something in it that is not actually grammatical, joiedevivre.

Comment: @ColinFine You yourself pointed out in your first comment that if it were not an idiom, you would say "Think about a woolly mammoth." It is okay to omit the preposition and article only because it is an idiom. You might also be right that quotation marks fix it. I'm just trying to help the OP understand that the reason it doesn't follow typical grammar rules is because it is an idiom.